# Laravel submit button doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, laravel-5, crud, laravel-routing, eloquent

i have a form with a submit button, I'm using get method to send values to get data from my database in PostgreSQL, so i have this in mi route

```
Route::get('informacion_entidad/{pass}','InformacionEntidadController@show');
```

in my controller i have this:

```
$sql="select valida('".$pass."')";

        $results = DB::select($sql);

        foreach ($results as $k => $v)
            $results = $v->valida;

        dd($results);
```

and my form like this:

```
<form method="get">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="pass" class="control-label">password</label>
       <input id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Ingrese el password" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
   <span class="btn-label">
       <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
   </span>
   submit
   </button>
</form>
```

the problem is, when i push my button, it gaves me this url

```
informacion_entidad?pass=das
```

but i need something like

```
informacion_entidad/password
```

how can i do that?

Comment: You are not setting your form's action attribute. Also you should never send passwords on `GET` requests, since the URL may be easily read by anyone. Use an `POST` request, and send your password in the request payload.

Comment: I already change to post an my route is like this:

Route::post('user/{pass}', ['as' => 'pass',  'uses' => 'InformacionEntidadController@show']);

but i dont want to show any url, just to redirect to another url after sending my password to the controller, and my controller now is like this:

$sql="select valida('".$pass."')";
        $results = DB::select($sql);
        foreach ($results as $k => $v)
            $results = $v->valida;
        return view("index");
        dd($results);

Answer (score 0):

the following link explains your problem for laravel 5.2 (which basically did not change to the current version) [form routes in Laravel 5.2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-routes-in-laravel-52?page=1)

also: you probably don't want to send your form via get (especially not passwords and the like)

looked for another link for you to get more information on laravel forms: [laravel-recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/124/opening-a-new-html-form)

I personally like the [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) site which has a lot of very helping videos which explain how to use everything.

Answer (score 0):

you should use hash make and check.

To store password in database, make hash of password and then save.

```
$password = Input::get('password_from_user'); 
$hashed = Hash::make($password); // save $hashed value
```

To verify password, get password stored of account from database

```
// $user is database object
// $inputs is Input from user
if( \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::check( $inputs['password'], $user['password']) == false) {
  // Password is not matching 
} else {
  // Password is matching 
}
```